# Justification isn't done in this part of my document

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
...

\begin{center}
\section*{Marco Te\'orico}
\end{center}

\textbf{Diodo:}
Es un componente electr\'onico de dos terminales que permite la circulaci\'on de la corriente el\'ectrica a trav\'es de \'el en un solo sentido. Este t\'ermino generalmente se usa para referirse al diodo semiconductor, el m\'as com\'un en la actualidad; consta de una pieza de cristal semiconductor conectada a dos terminales el\'ectricos.
De forma simplificada, la curva caracter\'istica de un diodo (I-V) consta de dos regiones: por debajo de cierta diferencia de potencial, se comporta como un circuito abierto (no conduce), y por encima de ella como un circuito cerrado con una resistencia el\'ectrica muy peque\~na. Debido a este comportamiento, se les suele denominar rectificadores, ya que son dispositivos capaces de suprimir la parte negativa de cualquier se\~nal, como paso inicial para convertir una corriente alterna en corriente continua.\cite{wiki:diode}

....
\end{document}
```

The error is: `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item`
and only this part of the text is not justified, why? I don't understand.
If you see, I use two columns and appears like a be focused.

I reviewed my document, one, two, three times, but i don´t find the `\item` missing. Help me please. If you can tell me the answer at the problem in Spanish it would be best, because I don't know so much English. Thanks

Comment: Do you have a ``\\`` to "end a paragraph" somewhere?

Comment: Your MWE does not provide enough information to resolve the problem, which probably occurs prior to this block of text.

Comment: Your example doesn't give any information, please edit it so that it generates the error you describe. That particular error is somewhat famous it almost never is caused by a missing item, but hard to say what caused it for you unless you show an example.

Comment: Esos problemas no se reproducen en tu ejemplo, así que ya nos contarás como te podríamos ayudar. Para hacer un buen ejemplo debes eliminar de tu archivo original todo lo que puedas **mientras** el problema siga existiendo (y no aparezcan otros, como por ejemplo `\cite{...}` sin bibliografía). Por otra parte, *por el amor de Dios*, pon `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` en el preámbulo y ya podrás escribir las tildes normalmente el 99,99% de las veces. Si el archivo no es UTF8, prueba con `latin9` u otra opción de ese paquete ¡pero **no** lo hagas al modo `prehist\'orico`!.

Comment: Quizas también debas usar `\paragraph{Diodo:}` en lugar de `\textbf{Diodo:}`. En vez de ordenar formatos concretos ("ponlo en negrita") suele ser mejor indicar estructuras ("esto es el título del párrafo"), y dejar que LaTeX lo formatee como corresponda, del mismo modo que ordenas `\section*{..}`  en lugar de ponerlo en letra grande en negrita y añadir espacios manualmente.

Comment: I was trying to guess how you generated that error. the smallest change that I can make to your example to generate that error is to add `\\ ` after  `\section*{Marco Te\'orico}` Does your original document have a construction such as `\section*{Marco Te\'orico}\\ ` ?